# Elasticsearch - Concatenate documents by recalculating mean, min, and max values

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-elasticsearch

I have an index which has latency values reported every 2 seconds. These documents contain timestamp, mean, min, and max. After an arbitrary period of time (say one or two days), I would like to concatenate these documents to reduce space requirements, decreasing resolution of the latency values to one per minute.

Is there a way to do this in Elasticsearch, or with a plugin? Or will I have to write a script which scrubs the previous days index and calculates new mean, min, max values for every minute - deleting the documents as it goes?

Comment: ES won't do that alone. You scroll over the previous day's index, do your computation and recreate a new index with the recomputed data.

Comment: Cheers. Do you know of any plugins which might have this functionality? If not, feel free to make that comment an answer to this question so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ES won't do that alone and I'm not aware of any plugins which do that.

One way to do it is to scroll over the previous day's index, do your computation and recreate a new index with the recomputed data. This could be done with any client-side language...

...or with Logstash using an `elasticsearch` input to read the previous day's index, an `aggregate` or `ruby` filter to aggregate the data and do the computation and an `elasticsearch` output to write the new index.

Comment: Nice suggestion. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

We are doing something similar for any given kibana4 tabular visualization, with time series data.

We have a PHP code that takes given Kibana visualization id, extracts its aggregations, prepares elastic search aggregation query for time histograms for that aggregation, with bucket size of the resolution that you want (1d, 1w, 1M).

Then we store results of that aggregation in a separate index.

The bigest problem with that approach is that you can not show that aggregated results in Kibana 4 anymore as the results are already aggregated, so to show these resolutions, on a graph, we need to use something else.

It would be awesome it there would be a Kibana plugin that does exactly that and displays graphs for pre-aggregated data, the way you would show them in Excel or something.

Comment: I've also ended up doing a similar thing in Python. Except that I'm extracting the results from the aggregate and making a document which is the same structure as the old. So I am able to plot in Kibana alongside the original documents. It's obviously slower, but you cut a lot of time by submitting documents in bulk.